# MPMoviePlayerController: sound but no picture in fullscreen mode

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm using the following code to play a movie on an iPad 1 running iOS6:

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myMovie.mov" ofType:@""]];
    self.moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];

    // Register to receive a notification when the movie has finished playing.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object:self.moviePlayer];

    // Use the new 3.2 style API
    self.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;

    [self.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];

    self.moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768);

    [self.uiView addSubview:self.moviePlayer.view];

     //[self.moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];

     [self.moviePlayer play];
```

This works.

If however I uncomment the line for `setFullscreen`, I get the movie audio but with a completely black screen, no picture.

I've tried changing the order of a few lines, in particular the `play` call and the `setFullscreen` call, with no effect.

**Update**

This question appears to be directly relevant:

[MPMoviePlayerController in full screen issue (showing blank black screen)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11043922/mpmovieplayercontroller-in-full-screen-issue)

Comment: Not really an answer to the question, but I've switched to MPMoviePlayerViewController, and it works fine for full screen video.

Answer (score 0):

first of all change this line :
 `[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myMovie.mov" ofType:@""]` to: 
 `[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myMovie" ofType:@"mov"]` and try again

Comment: No change, but I'd be surprised if this did affect anything. Did it help out with a problem you were having?

Answer (score 0):

Use this as its working for me:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myMovie" ofType:@"mov"]];
MPMoviePlayerViewController *movieView = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]initWithContentURL:url];
movieView.moviePlayer.scalingMode =  MPMovieScalingModeFill;
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
        [movieView.moviePlayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,480,320)];
else
        [movieView.moviePlayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,1024,768)];
movieView.moviePlayer.view.userInteractionEnabled = FALSE;
movieView.moviePlayer.controlStyle=0;
[movieView setFullscreen:YES];
self.view=movieView.view;
```

Comment: Thanks! Interesting. I tried you code, and the bit that seems to make a difference is the last line -- the setting of the movie player view directly to replace the current view make the video visible. Unfortunately the movie player shows the movie on its side!